# Output data from SQLALCHEMY into a file.txt

Tags: python-2.7, file-io, sqlalchemy

I am trying to print the data, shown below, and export it into a text file. I have tables the correspond to these instantiated objects.

```
#ASSESSMENT 
    api = BaseAPI()

    assessment1 = api.create_assessment('Situation Awareness', 'Developing better skills',u2, v3, category=[l,dm,tc,sa], element=[sa1,sa2,sa3,dm1,dm2,dm3,ct1,ct2,ct3,l1,l2,l3])

    assessment2 = api.create_assessment('Decision-Making', 'better decisions', u1, v2, category=[l,dm,tc,sa], element=[sa1,sa2,sa3,dm1,dm2,dm3,ct1,ct2,ct3,l1,l2,l3])

    assessment3 = api.create_assessment('Leadership', 'defining new leaders',u3, v1, category=[l,dm,tc,sa], element=[sa1,sa2,sa3,dm1,dm2,dm3,ct1,ct2,ct3,l1,l2,l3])
```

The query method I am using is:

```
    import sys

    class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, filename="Default.log"):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(filename, "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)

sys.stdout = Logger('DataOutput.txt')

def analystview(object):
    for a in self.session.query(Assessment).\
    filter(Assessment.user_id==Assessment.user_id).\
    filter(Assessment.name == Assessment.name).all():
        for a in assessments:
            print(a.name, a.text, a.user_id)

api = BaseAPI()
analystview(api)
```

What am I doing wrong with the above code that it is not printing the output from my query??

Answer (score 0):

This format works! Nonetheless, is there a better method to the process of output? I mean, a cleaner method to outputting queries to a text file?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import sys
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('some.db') # used sqlite3 to go through results/data
cur = db.cursor()
query = ("SELECT * FROM users")
lines = cur.execute(query)
data = cur.fetchall()


class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, filename="Default.log"):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(filename, "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)

sys.stdout = Logger('DataOutput.txt') #name of the text file
print(data) #has to be after the sys.stdout to print out results
```